# Peek and Pop on UITableView cells fails with UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, peek-pop

Peek and Pop is working with a `UISearchController`. However, Peek and Pop stops working once you start searching the table using `updateSearchResults`.

I've extended Apple's [Table Search with UISearchController demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/TableSearch_UISearchController/Introduction/Intro.html) to support Peek and Pop as an example:
[image]

Problem is when I start searching the table, Peek and Pop doesn't work anymore. It just select highlights it:
[image]

The updates I made were to `MainTableViewController` are:

```
class MainTableViewController: BaseTableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
            registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
        }
    }
}

extension MainTableViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let indexPath = tableView?.indexPathForRow(at: location),
            let cell = tableView?.cellForRow(at: indexPath),
            let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController
                else { return nil }

        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame

        controller.product = products[0]

        return controller
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        guard let controller = viewControllerToCommit as? DetailViewController else { return }
        controller.product = products[0]
        show(controller, sender: self)
    }
}
```

Is the search context controller interfering with peek and pop (could even be the keyboard)? I can get it to work when the table initially all data, but it does not once I start using the search. I attached a [working sample here](http://ge.tt/79P8imi2) if you want to run it and see the issue.

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots and more details, thx :)

Comment: I can confirm it's not the keyboard that's blocking the peek and pop. I dismissed it and the issue remains.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont have 3d touch iPhone, and in simulator there is no facility provide by xcode. I want to help you but unfortunately I cant So sorry for you

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, in your `MainTableViewController.viewDidLoad()` you need to also register your `resultsTableController.tableView`, since that is a separate view that will receive peek/pop information:

```
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    previewingContext = registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
    if let resultVC = searchController.searchResultsController as? ResultsTableController {
        resultVC.registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: resultVC.tableView)
    }
}
```

When testing this solution, I noticed a strange problem, that the first row in the result set wasn't peekable, and blank rows in the result set WERE peekable. So, the second fix in `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)`:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
    guard let tableView = previewingContext.sourceView as? UITableView,
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
```

In your original code, it was using the `tableView` property on the `MainTableViewController` instead of the `tableView` that was the `sourceView` for the interaction.

Now, this works when you're searching, and when you're not. However, when you've entered the search, but haven't entered any search text yet, the `UISearchController` is active, but the `UITableView` is the one from `MainTableViewController`, and you **cannot** register a view as a source view twice. So, we have a little more work to do:

```
// local property to store the result from registerForPreviewing(with:sourceView:)
var previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing?

func didPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let context = previewingContext {
        unregisterForPreviewing(withContext: context)
        previewingContext = searchController.registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
    }
}

func didDismissSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let context = previewingContext {
        searchController.unregisterForPreviewing(withContext: context)
        previewingContext = registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
    }
}
```

Basically, when the `UISearchController` is presented, we unregister `MainTableViewController` and register the search controller. When it is dismissed, we do the reverse.

With these changes, peek and pop work in all three states.

Comment: @TruMan1, was my answer helpful?

Comment: This works fine as long as you have a separate searchResultsController. However, if you use the table view controller itself to show the search results, searchController.searchResultsController is nil (as per Apples documents: "searchResultsController: The view controller that displays the search results. Specify nil if you want to display the search results in the same view controller that displays your searchable content."

Comment: I couldn't get Peek and Pop to work with the searchController.  The searchController.registerForPreviewing(...) did the job for me, i just set it in viewDidLoad. I spent hours trying different things, but with self.registerForPreviewing(...) it didn't call the implemented delegate methods. Thanks.

Comment: The suggestion by @dkrdennis worked for me, however, I had to call `registerForPreviewing(with:sourceView:)` on the search controller after calling it on my view controller holding the search controller.

Comment: After further testing, I'd like to change my comment above slightly. I found that it works best when the search controller is registered for previewing in `willPresentSearchController(_:)` of UISearchControllerDelegate. At the same time, the view controller should be unregistered. Vice versa in `willDismissSearchController(_:)`.