# 3d Peek & Pop for search results

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller, peek-pop

I use a Search Bar to filter my Table View. I display the search results in the same view controller that displays the searchable content. It works fine. Except one thing - **3d Peek and Pop is not working for the search results**.
I did tried the ‘Peek & Pop’ check box in Storyboard segue. I did tried programming peek & pop in my TableViewController. Result is the same: peek & pop works for table view cells but not for search result cells.

Here is the search and peek & pop code pieces:

```
    // Add a search bar
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height)

    // Register for preview
    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
        previewingContext = registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filterContent(for: searchText)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate methods
    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {        
        guard let tableView = previewingContext.sourceView as? UITableView,
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath),
            let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlarmViewController") as? AlarmViewController
        else { return nil }
        detailVC.alarm = alarms[indexPath.row]
        previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame       
        return detailVC
    }

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
        show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
    }
```

Has anyone any ideas how to implement peek & pop for search results?

I guess the main problem is how to register for previewing the UISearchController?..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Peek and Pop on UITableView cells fails with UISearchController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42196749/peek-and-pop-on-uitableview-cells-fails-with-uisearchcontroller)

Comment: @DaveWeston Thanx for your input! I did check you suggestion and unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Maybe because I reuse the same Table View Controller for the search results. In the topic you mention a separate view controller is used for the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work. There were couple of 'new kid on the block' mistakes. The correct code:

```
// Add a search bar
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.delegate = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
// Hide search bar on detailed view and preserve search results
    self.definesPresentationContext = true

// Register for preview
if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .available {
    previewingContext = registerForPreviewing(with: self, sourceView: tableView)
}

func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
        filterContent(for: searchText)
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

// MARK: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate methods
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {        
    guard let tableView = previewingContext.sourceView as? UITableView,
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location),
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath),
        let detailVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AlarmViewController") as? AlarmViewController
    else { return nil }
    detailVC.alarm = (searchController.isActive) ? searchResults[(indexPath.row)] : alarms[indexPath.row]
    previewingContext.sourceRect = cell.frame       
    return detailVC
}

func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commit viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    show(viewControllerToCommit, sender: self)
}
```

In short:
1) added delegating for searchController
2) using searchResults in UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate if searchController.isActive

Hope it helps someone.